# How to pass nested styling to a component in React

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using [this](https://ant.design/components/card/) card component, and I'd like to build on top of it. More specifically, I'd like to inline change the background color of titles. The way I though of it, it would look something like this:

```
<Card title='Produção e reembolso' style={{
  ant-card-head: {
    backgroundColor: '#232323'
  }
}} >
  <div> R$ {productionAmount} </div>
</Card>
```

This doesn't work, as React thinks ant-card-head is a property name. Is there a way to do this, or I'll have to use/create a different component?

**Edit**

Rendered HTML looks like this

```
<div class="ant-card ant-card-bordered">
  <div class="ant-card-head">
    <h3 class="ant-card-head-title">Produção e reembolso</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="ant-card-body">
    <div><!-- react-text: 150 --> R$ <!-- /react-text --></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what would `ant-card-head` be doing in this case? why not just pass backgroundColor directly?

Comment: Hmm, this could actually work, if I send the 'bodyStyle' with background: white

Comment: It didn't work, ant-card-head have a background-color: white property, so I need to overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a common object having styles and pick up stuff from there, you have to declare stuff separately and use.

```
const AllStyles = {
  "ant-card-head": {
    backgroundColor: '#232323'
  },
  "another-thing": {
    backgroundColor: '#ff00aa'
  }
};
<Card title='Produção e reembolso' style={AllStyles["ant-card-head"]} >
<AnotherElem title='Produção e empréstimo' style={AllStyles["another-thing"]} >
```

If you just want to inline styles only for this element you do this

```
<Card title='Produção e reembolso' style={{
  backgroundColor: '#232323'
}} >
```

Comment: Problem is, the card component renders this "ant-card-head", so I don't have direct access to it, and therefore cant put the style on it.

Comment: You can try styling it via CSS

Comment: Well yeah, but I didnt want to create 8 different classes for 8 different title colors. Thats my last option, but I have it in mind. Thanks though